# Swift. Alternate items in 2 arrays merge

Tags: arrays, swift, merge

I've these arrays.

```
let array1 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 55]
let array2 = [11, 22, 33]
```

I want this output in only one array

```
[10, 11, 20, 22, 30, 33, 40, 50, 55]
```

In case the second array size is bigger than first one.

```
let array1 = [10, 20, 30]
let array2 = [11, 22, 33, 45, 56, 78]
```

Output

```
[10, 11, 20, 22, 30, 33, 45, 56, 78]
```

Is there a way without loop the arrays in a for?

Thanks

Comment: Are the source arrays always sorted in increasing order? Can we assume that the result is sorted in increasing order? What would be the expected result for merging `[1, 2, 3]` with `[4, 5, 6]`?

Comment: The source can be in sorted in order or not. The example can be confused.

The result for your example may be. 1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6

Answer (score -1):

You can use `+` operator for arrays, remove duplicates using `Set` and sort result:

```
let array1 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 55]
let array2 = [11, 22, 33]

let mixedArray = Set(array1 + array2).sort(<)
print(mixedArray)
//[10, 11, 20, 22, 30, 33, 40, 50, 55]
```

This works for any input array sizes.

Comment: Sorry but the arrays not always can be in order